# Nginx 404 but file exists

Tags: http, nginx, webserver

I have an Nginx server block that handles requests and simply serves files from a directory. However, even though the file `index.html` exists, it does not serve it, not at `/` nor at `/index.html`. This problem also occurs for files that I know to exist in the site root directory.

```
server {
    

    root /var/www/mysite/html/;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name example.com;

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ = 404;
    }

}
```

`example.com` should simply load the contents of `index.html`, but it does not.

Comment: Would you please add `access.log` and `error.log` to the question?

Comment: @Andromeda (apologies for the egregiously late response) neither `access.log` nor `error.log` were relevant to the issue I was having. I fixed it at the time, but I seem to have forgotten what the solution was now. I will post the solution if I remember/find it. All I remember is that it was within this file (`/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/whatever`). (it may have been that extra curly bracket at the end)